# Replace html list with Php array

Tags: php, html

So my assignment is that i needed to create a html list from an array and make a drop-down menu from an array as well and if i choose a particular subject it should only show that subject with its teachers.

i made this but if i add a new subject in my array it breaks so i need to find a solution that if i add another item to the array it should work without changing code (i need to use an foreach and if statement) PS: I'm stuck for hours, Thanks for helping me.

my code :

```
<?php
$School = array(
    'science' => array(
        'teachersmith',
        'anotherteachersmith'
    ),
    'english' => array(
        'mr.vincent',
        'teachermichael',
        'coolestteacherever'
    ),
    'math' => array(
        'mathteacher',
        'mr.jason'
    ),
); 

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        switch($_POST["subjectoptions"]) {
            case "science":
                unset( $School['english'] );
                unset( $School['math'] );
                break;
        case "english":
            unset( $School['science'] );
            unset( $School['math'] );
            break;
        case "math":
            unset( $School['science'] );
            unset( $School['english'] );
    } 
}

echo "<ul class=listclass>";
foreach ($School as $subject => $teachername){
    echo "<li class=listclass>"."$subject". "</li>";

    echo "<ul class=listclass>";
    foreach ($teachername as $cNamen){
        echo "<li class=listclass>"."$cNamen". "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>

<form method='POST'>
    <select name="subjectoptions">
        <option>Choose a subject</option>
            <?php 
            foreach ($School as $subject2 => $aDocentnames){ 
                echo "<option value=$subject2>$subject2</option>";
            } ?>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="show selected subject"/>
    <input type="submit" name="reset" value="show all subjects"/>
    </select>
</form>
```

Comment: Welcome. "_it breaks_" What does that mean? What breaks? Note: `<input>` inside `<select>` is not valid. `<ul>` inside `<ul>` is not valid, place it inside `<li>`

Comment: @kerbholz the switch is hardcoded so it won´t work if 1st level of $School changes.

Comment: @kerbholz yea, i'm trying to find a solution for it but nothing seems to work

Comment: Some punctuation would help, it is very tricky to read one long sentence.

Comment: @AndyG does this make it more clear? :)

Comment: @joko13 could you explain how your solution works? Thank you.

Comment: @Simonn I´ve now added comments to explain my approach.

Comment: @joko13 just a quick question what does the = do on "$new_array[$_POST["subjectoptions"]] = $School[$_POST["subjectoptions"]]; "?

Comment: It creates a new array that only contains the desired info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$School = array(
    'science' => array(
        'teachersmith',
        'anotherteachersmith'
    ),
    'english' => array(
        'mr.vincent',
        'teachermichael',
        'coolestteacherever'
    ),
    'math' => array(
        'mathteacher',
        'mr.jason'
    ),
); 

$final_array = $School; // To not lose the $School array we store a copy as $final_array

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
        // We create a new array with $_POST["subjectoptions"] (e.g. science) and subarrays with the 2nd level of $School[$_POST["subjectoptions"]] (e.g. $School['science'] which gives us teachersmith and anotherteachersmith)
        $new_array[$_POST["subjectoptions"]] = $School[$_POST["subjectoptions"]]; 

        // Since we now want to work with the new array we set final_array to the new_array
        $final_array = $new_array;
    } 

    if (isset($_POST['reset'])){
        // If the reset button is clicked we restore the original array
        $final_array = $School;
    } 

echo "<ul class=listclass>";
foreach ($final_array as $subject => $teachername){
    echo "<li class=listclass>"."$subject". "</li>";

    echo "<ul class=listclass>";
    foreach ($teachername as $cNamen){
        echo "<li class=listclass>"."$cNamen". "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
echo "</ul>";
?>

<form method='POST'>
    <select name="subjectoptions">
        <option>Choose a subject</option>
            <?php 
            foreach ($School as $subject2 => $aDocentnames){ 
                echo "<option value=$subject2>$subject2</option>";
            } ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="show selected subject"/>
</form>
<form method='POST'>
    <input type="submit" name="reset" value="show all subjects"/>
</form>
```

Comment: @joko13 Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, actually this is not an space where you ask for help about some assignment. But you have a problem and need some help to sort it out.

Here is the solution-

**This is your array:**

```
<?php
$School = array(
    'science' => array(
        'teachersmith',
        'anotherteachersmith'
    ),
    'english' => array(
        'mr.vincent',
        'teachermichael',
        'coolestteacherever'
    ),
    'math' => array(
        'mathteacher',
        'mr.jason'
    )
);
```

Here i check the form is submitted or not and also check the subject is chosen or not. If a subject is choose then i create a loop with the subject selected as an index to that array. It shows the subject name and the teacher's list.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['subjectoptions'])){ $subjectoptions = $_POST['subjectoptions'];?>
    <ul class='listclass'>
        <ol class='listclass'><?php echo $_POST['subjectoptions'];?></ol>
        <?php foreach($School[$subjectoptions] as $teachername){?>
        <li class='listclass'><?php echo $teachername.".";?></li>
        <?php }?>
    </ul>
<?php }?>
```

This is the form and i use an attribute to keep selected the item is select.

```
<form method='POST'>
    <select name="subjectoptions">
        <option>Choose a subject</option>
        <?php 
        $subjectName = array_keys($School);
        foreach ($subjectName as $subject){ 
            echo "<option ".(($subject == @$_POST['subjectoptions']) ? 'selected' : '')." value='".$subject."'>".$subject."</option>";
        }?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="show selected subject"/>
    <input type="submit" name="reset" value="show all subjects"/>
</form>
```